# how to fix a responsive navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation, responsive-design

I have a question that was based on some of my previous work.

I am building a navigation that is responsive.

The problem occurs when,

Press grey block to open nav -works fine. 
Press grey block to hide nav - works fine

However once you hide the nav and increase the size of the screen to over 800px the main nav is still hidden, it does not reappear.

Can any body assist with this issue?

http://jsfiddle.net/9jPe9/

```
 body {
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #444;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
#wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#wrap-inner {
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top:80px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#wrap-inner-profile {
    padding: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
}
#content {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 970px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    color: #4083a9;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #205f82;
}
ul, ol, h1, h2, h3, h4, p {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    ;
}
p {
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
img:hover {
    opacity: .7;
}
/* =============================================================================
   HEADER
   ========================================================================== */
 #header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 67px;
    background: white;
    z-index: 9997;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(6, 8, 8, 0.0980392) 0px 3px 3px;
    box-shadow: rgba(6, 8, 8, 0.0980392) 0px 3px 3px;
}
#header-inner {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 12px;
    max-width: 970px;
}
#logo {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 20px 0 0;
}
#logo a {
    display: block;
    width: 107px;
    height: 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 50%;
    background-image: url(../img/home/oh-holla.png);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
}
#logo img {
    height: 0;
}
#logo a:hover {
    opacity: .6;
}
#nav {
    margin: 1px 0px 0 0px;
    color: #777;
    padding:0px;
    float:right;
}
#nav>li {
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
#nav>li>a {
    display: block;
    height: 66px;
    line-height: 66px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#toggle-nav {
    display: none;
}
#right-nav {
    margin: 1px 0px 0 0px;
    color: #777;
    padding:0px;
    float:right;
    margin-top: 26px;
}
#right-nav li {
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
#right-nav li a {
    display: block;
    height: 66px;
    line-height: 66px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#signin {
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
#login {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
/* =============================================================================
  NAVIGATION MEDIA MAX 800PX
   ========================================================================== */
 @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #header {
        position: fixed;
        height: 57px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(6, 8, 8, 0.0980392) 0px 3px 3px;
        box-shadow: rgba(6, 8, 8, 0.0980392) 0px 3px 3px;
        background: green;
    }
    #toggle-nav {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        display: block;
        width: 48px;
        height: 40px;
        text-indent: -9999px;
        background: url('../img/home/burger-menu.png') 20px 20px no-repeat;
        opacity: .5;
        background:black;
    }
    #logo a {
        display: block;
        height: 40px;
        margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    }
    #logo {
        float: none;
        padding-right: 0;
        text-align: left;
    }
    #nav {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
        text-align: left;
        position: absolute;
        top: 57px;
        display: none;
    }
    #nav li {
        position: relative;
        float: none;
        margin-right: 0;
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 12px;
        background: #323232;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    #nav li:hover {
        background: #2e2e2e;
    }
    #header-inner {
        width: auto;
        padding: 0;
        height: 57px;
        background: pink;
    }
    #nav li a {
        height: auto;
        padding: 15px;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        line-height: 1;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        background: white;
    }
    #wrap-inner {
        padding-top: 60px;
    }
    #right-nav {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: -10px;
        right: 20px;
        background: none;
    }
    #livefeed {
        -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(6, 8, 8, 0.0980392) 0px 3px 3px;
        box-shadow: rgba(6, 8, 8, 0.0980392) 0px 3px 3px;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with your css.. the css for media having lessthan 800px is fine.. but the css no lessthan is not fine.. you put `#toggle-nav {
    display: none;
}` that's why it was not working.. just check in the following fiddle.. [http://jsfiddle.net/9jPe9/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/9jPe9/3/)

Comment: Hi, this doesnt work?

Comment: I only applied the styling for toggle-nav.. try after adding all the necessary styles from the media css..

Comment: your fiddle.. [http://jsfiddle.net/9jPe9/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/9jPe9/4/)..

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, change:

```
/* =============================================================================
  NAVIGATION MEDIA MAX 800PX
   ========================================================================== */
 @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
```

into

```
/* =============================================================================
  NAVIGATION MEDIA MAX 800PX
   ========================================================================== */
 @media screen {
```

to stop this issue. I don't really know why you would want max-width as 800px, but if you really need it, try putting it in the body of #header

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Use media query only screen

Answer (score 0):

in the CSS where you have:

```
...
/* =============================================================================
  NAVIGATION MEDIA MAX 800PX
   ========================================================================== */
 @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
...
```

This parameter max-width:800px is giving you trouble. Change it or remove it.

Comment: Hi, What do you suggest changing it to?

Comment: Hi, don't know why you've put it there in the first place. These limitations are usually set when you work on mobile CSS and you want to cover several screen sizes. But in your case you can just remove the "and (max-width: 800px)" part and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Its just simple. I have updated the JS fiddle, Please check it.

http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/9jPe9/2/

Add this media query in the CSS

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
     #nav {
         display:block!important;
}
 }
```

Comment: The other nav links are hidden when you increase screen size after hidding drop down menu

Comment: Did you check the JS fiddle, I don't see any problem here. If exists, could you send a screenshot? So that I can understand what do you think.